# Difference between key={`note${note.id}`}> and key={note.id} in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am following a React tutorial and the author has some code like:

```
<li key={`note${note.id}`}>
        <Note task={note.task} />
      </li>
```

however, the same code also works if you simply do:

```
  <li className="note" key={note.id}>
                <Note task={note.task}/>
            </li>
```

what is the purpose of the `note$ before the actual note.id in the first example? Both work, only curious why this is there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`` <li key={`note${note.id}`}> `` is equivalent to `<li key={"note" + note.id}>`.

In React, the `key` prop is used to reconcile elements between renders. All children elements of a DOM component must have unique keys. See [Reconciliation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html).

Assigning the value `note.id` to the `key` prop of your `<li>` elements ensures that all of them have different and unique keys. Prefixing it with `"note"` ensures that there is no overlap if your parent element also contains other elements.

Here is an example where prefixing the keys is mandatory, since ids can be shared between notes and drafts.

```js
var notes = [
  { id: 0, message: 'foo' },
  { id: 1, message: 'bar' },
];
var drafts = [
  { id: 0, message: 'foo' },
  { id: 1, message: 'bar' },
];
var children = notes.map(function(note) {
  return <li key={`note${note.id}`}><Note /></li>;
}).concat(drafts.map(function(draft) {
  return <li key={`draft${draft.id}`}><Draft /></li>;
}));
return <ul>{children}</ul>
```

Comment: for reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings
"es6 template strings" is the official term for the ` syntax

Answer (score 4):

The two examples are setting different keys.

Assume the note object has an id of 1.

The top example `key={'notes${note.id}'}>` is setting the key attribute equal to 'note1'.

The bottom example `key={note.id}` is setting the key equal to '1'.

They will both work because the key attribute is just used to uniquely identify children of a component.  The top one key="note1" is probably better, just because it is more descriptive and specific and readable.  You could imagine a React component that has more than one type of child, and their keys could clash if they were both given simple numeric keys.

This

```
`${variableName}`
```

syntax is the new ES6 Javascript string formatting syntax, similar to string interpolation in python or ruby.  See the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

Comment: so is it just the same as note + note.id? I think that is much more readable , why not use that?

Comment: note: official term for this syntax is "es6 template strings"

Comment: @user3839821 it's a new feature in es6 that isn't in all browsers yet.  I believe the guys behind JSX are on the board trying to push templating syntax, so eventually the plan is probably to use the new syntax

Comment: @user3839821 in this simple example, yes you could do 'note' + note.id and it would be readable enough.  If you are doing anything more complicated than that, or concatenating several strings together, using the template string syntax can look a lot cleaner.  Another reason is just developer preference:  template strings are new to Javascript, but devs coming from other languages are going to be used to using them.